# Django (1.8) Ajax form BooleanField always returns True

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm writing a Django form with two BooleanFields:

```
distributive = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
    attrs={'id':'distributive'}),required=False, initial=False)
transitivity = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(
    attrs={'id':'transitivity'}),required=False, initial=False)
```

I'm gathering the data from this form in a View:

```
class MyFormView(View):
    ...
    def post(self, request):
        form = VerbQueryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            transitivity = form.cleaned_data['transitivity']
            distributive = form.cleaned_data['distributive']
            print(type(transitivity))  #debugging
            print(transitivity)        #debugging
            print(type(distributive))  #debugging
            print(distributive)        #debugging
```

Whether I check the the boxes or not, both fields return as False bools. I'm very confused.

Any insight would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Alasdair had some insight: 
 My manual addition of id attributes to the form fields overrides Django's default id settings, and so the browser returns no data from the fields.

Unfortunately I need to access those form fields through a javaScript file, because I am using Ajax. I'm a rookie at both JavaScript and Ajax, so I'm not sure how to work around this.

Here is my Ajax post request code:

```
$.ajax({
        url : "/verbquery/", // the endpoint
        type : "POST", // http method
        data : { english_gloss : $('#english_gloss').val(), person : $('#person').val(), number : $('#number').val(),
                 mode : $('#mode').val(), transitivity : $('#transitivity').val(), distributive : $('#distributive').val(),
                 voice : $('#voice').val()}, // data sent with the post request
```

Simply changing the ids for transitivity and distributive to django's default id_transitivity and id_distributive does not get them into the dictionary. I know this wasn't the original point of the post but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try printing `request.POST` to see what data the browser is submitting.

Comment: `required=False` is for blank values. a `Checkbox` could be checked or unchecked, what would be the blank value? Have you tried removing `required` param?

Comment: @Gocht I don't think that's the issue here. If you have `required=True` for a `BooleanField`, then the form is only valid when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: @Gocht -- I tried that, but unfortunately it had no effect.

Comment: @Alasdair I tried your suggestion and got some interesting results. The QueryDict has 'on' as values for both keys 'transitivity' and 'distributive'

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for the advice about removing the ID attr. I'm now stuck because the JavaScript file I'm using for the form (I have to because of Ajax) accessed those fields through the id attributes. So with the ID attr removed in the form, the fields no longer make it into the QueryDict.

Comment: I deleted my answer, because I think it was incorrect. Overriding the `id` should be ok, it is the `name` of the field that is important. So I'm not sure what the problem is. Perhaps posting your javascript that is making the request might help.

Comment: @Alasdair Ok, I've added it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an issue with your javascript, not the Django form.

`$('#transitivity').val()` will always return `'on'` for a checkbox.

Try the following instead:

```
$('#transitivity').is(':checked') ? 'on' : ''
```